# OpenSSH RSA publickey mysterious auth failure

Tags: linux, openssh, public-key

I'm not new to configuring OpenSSH to require public key authentication, or generating keys and setting up access via authorized_keys, but this one has me stumped.

I made a Linux Mint box for my in-laws.  This had the added benefits of not having to pay for Windows, and allowing me to remotely administer the system when something came up.  They moved, and immediately after the move they called to tell me that the box never gets to a GUI after the login prompt.  I have an account with a key to access it (tested it before giving it to them) just for this purpose right?

Now the problem:

```
localuser@client:~
$ ssh remoteuser@server
remoteuser@server: Permission denied (publickey).
localuser@client:~
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa remoteuser@server
remoteuser@server: Permission denied (publickey).
```

This sucks, and I'd rather keep to social distancing and not make other current events worse (note localuser != remoteuser).

Workaround:

I made a simple bash script and put that and my public key up to be easily downloadable.  I talk my FIL through a quick `curl -sL https://www.example.net/script | bash-` command on the console over the phone under a different account.  The script downloads the key into this users's authorized_keys and sets up permissions on the directory and the file to make the OpenSSH daemon happy.

Results:

```
localuser@client:~
$ ssh remoteuser2@server
Enter passphrase for key '/home/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa':
remoteuser2@server:~
$ su remoteuser
Password:
remoteuser@server:/home/remoteuser
$ sudo diff -q -s .ssh/authorized_keys ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
[sudo] password for remoteuser:
Files .ssh/authorized_keys and /home/remoteuser/.ssh/authorized_keys are identical
```

That solves the immediate problem.  I can get in and I can do as I need, but I'm still perplexed.  I've double checked the permissions on `/home/remoteuser/.ssh` on `/home/remoteuser2/.ssh` and their respective `authorized_keys` files.  They all match.  Then it gets super weird.  While the above session is still active:

```
localuser@client:~
$ ssh remoteuser@server
Enter passphrase for key '/home/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa':
remoteuser@server:~
$
```

Ok... WTH? I log out of all sessions and I can still get in without the workaround.  This is getting maddening.  So I reboot the remote box, and POW! I can't get in unless I use the workaround first.

Thoughts?  I'm beyond confused.  It doesn't work, but if I login as someone else then `su` to me, it works.  And once a reboot takes place, I have to use the trick again. To be absolutely clear if it matters: remoteuser, remoteuser2 and localuser are all different.

Comment: Have you checked the server's sshd logs to any extent? (Have you tried enabling _verbose_ logs using the LogLevel option?)

Comment: I looked at the sshd tagged entries in auth.log and journalctl. They just say that the client has disconnected.  I'll take a look at upping the LogLevel to see what I get. I also set triple verbose on the client "-vvv" and on a successful attempt at using a sha256 hash of the public key the client says something like "received packet type: 60", where the failed attempts it says "received packet type: 51".  If I knew what the codes meant that would be helpful too.  I copied the exact messages into a Google search expecting at the very least to find the source somewhere, if not a StackExchange.

Comment: These two are defined in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252 sections 6 and 7 and they just mean "auth failed / succeeded".

Comment: Thanks for the link to the RFC, I'll have to squirrel that away. That clears the codes up.  They are just the generic authentication failure (51) and publickey authentication success (60).  At least I know the server has been explicit about what happened, even if the standard log level didn't explicitly state their was any authentication failure.  I'll try your LogLevel suggestion when I can keep my eyes open.

Comment: After setting the LogLevel to DEBUG I get: "Could not open authorized keys '/home/remoteuser/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory"    This doesn't make sense though because it finds it later once I have logged into remoteuser2 then su'd to remoteuser.

Comment: Do that, then run `findmnt` to check if the homedir is actually mounted from elsewhere (eCryptFS perhaps).

Comment: The answer is eCryptFS.  When I tested it, I was logged in locally and my home directory had already been decrypted.  I set this up when I built the box, and I was not aware of this incompatibility.  It makes sense, but I hadn't put the pieces together before.  Thanks for the great help, you are among the better folks around here.  I was originally afraid I'd get a standard RTFM response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I built the machine, I turned on home directory encryption for my user.  This prevents sshd from reading my authorized_keys file, as it is encrypted.  When I login to another account and `su` to mine, I'm decrypting my home directory.  This is why subsequent logins succeed and why attempts after the next reboot fail again. The comment train below the question has all the troubleshooting steps.  Props to anonymous user, user1686 for helping me figure this one out.  I really wish you were a named user so I could mark your answer to give you the reputation.

Steps to fix:

maintain encrypted home: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47122/cant-do-ssh-public-key-login-under-encrypted-home

OR

remove home directory encryption: https://ixnfo.com/en/disabling-ecryptfs-encryption-at-home-directory.html

I have not specifically done either, but I have no reason to believe they will not work.

Comment: OR, change sshd's AuthorizedKeysFile to additionally check a location outside of /home.